# How to convert a cell's frame's origin in terms of the view controller containing the tableview?

Tags: ios, ipad, tableview

I have a TableView in a ViewController, when I select a cell, I want to check if its below a certain *y* limit.

that y limit is in terms of the view of the viewController.

I took cell's origin and converted it in terms of ViewController's view. 
Here I have used the method of UIView class : `convertPoint:fromView:`

Here I have passed tableView itself as the fromView parameter considering it is the direct parent view of a cell and the frame of the cell will be interms of the tableView.

I see some increase in the y-value of the new point that I get than what I should have been getting.

Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CGRect rectOfCellInTableView = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGRect rectOfCellInSuperview = [tableView convertRect:rectOfCellInTableView toView:[tableView superview]];

NSLog(@"cell rect is : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(rectOfCellInSuperview));
```

Answer (score 3):

try this..

```
CGRect newPosition = [theCell convertRect:theCell.frame toView:yourViewController.view];
```

this will give you position of cell in terms of yourViewController

Comment: Ohh.. I can use the cell itself!

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4

```
let rectOfCellInTableView = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
let rectOfCellInSuperview = tableView.convert(rectOfCellInTableView, to: tableView.superview)
print("cell rect is : \(rectOfCellInSuperview)")

let newPosition = cell.convert(cell.frame, to: yourViewController.view)
```

Thanks to Warewolf & Prashant Nikam